# How to call an instance of a class defined inside a method of an outer class

Tags: java

```
class Outer{

    public void Method(){

    int i=10;
    System.out.println(i);
    Class InsideMethod{
        //
    }
}
```

Question : How can I call InsideMethod object outside of the method

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 5):

This snippet illustrates the various possibilities:

```
public class Outer {

  void onlyOuter() { System.out.println("111"); }
  void common() { System.out.println("222"); }

  public class Inner {
    void common() { System.out.println("333"); }
    void onlyInner() {
      System.out.println("444");// Output: "444"
      common();                 // Output: "333"
      Outer.this.common();      // Output: "222"
      onlyOuter();              // Output: "111"
    }
  }
}
```

Note:

- A method of inner class hides a similarly named method of the outer class. Hence, the `common();` call dispatches the implementation from the inner class.
- The use of the `OuterClass.this` construct for specifying that you want to dispatch a method from the outer class (to bypass the hiding)
- The call `onlyOuter()` dispatches the method from `OuterClass` as this is the inner-most enclosing class that defines this method.

Answer (score 3):

If I've understood correctly what you want, you could do:

```
OuterClass.this
```

Answer (score 2):

> **defined inside a method** of an outer
>   class

If its defined inside a method then its scope is limited to that method only.

Comment: we  can call : new ClassName().Method();

Comment: Yes we can. But we can not access variables inside that method.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've understood of your question... (see the example below), the instance of class 'Elusive' defined within a method of an outer class **cannot** be referenced from outside of method 'doOuter'.

```
public class Outer {

    public void doOuter() {
        class Elusive{

        }
        // you can't get a reference to 'e' from anywhere other than this method
        Elusive e = new Elusive(); 
    }

    public class Inner {

        public void doInner() {

        }
    }

}
```